# Otimização de Query - MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Saudações, senhores!
Venho mais uma vez recorrer a orientação dos mestres do DB!
Como da vez passada tenho uma query que retorna um resultado bem específico e que funciona,a mas está lento e a medida que o banco cresce, mais lento fica. Segue o modelo abaixo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT V1_PAIS_NOME_PT AS PAIS,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_PAIS_NOME_PT = PAIS) AS TOTAIS,
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT V1_IP) FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_PAIS_NOME_PT = PAIS) AS UNICOS

FROM `TV1-VISITAS` WHERE V1_OS NOT LIKE '%bot%'
    AND MONTH(V1_HORA) = MONTH(NOW())

ORDER BY TOTAIS DESC;
```

Muito grato pela atenção de vocês!

Answer (score 0):

Galera, agradeço aqueles que visualizaram mesmo que não tiveram condições de responder seja pelo motivo que for. Consegui resolver e vou postar aqui a solução para quem tiver o mesmo problema consiguir resolver. Coisa pra lá de simples, pura falta de atenção... Rsrs

```
SELECT V1_PAIS_NOME_PT AS PAIS,
    COUNT(V1_PAIS_NOME_PT) AS TOTAIS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT V1_IP) AS UNICOS
FROM `TV1-VISITAS`
WHERE V1_OS NOT LIKE '%bot%'
    AND MONTH(V1_HORA) = MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY PAIS
ORDER BY TOTAIS DESC;
```

Ao invés de fazer um novo **SELECT** dentro de cada consulta, vai apenas contar de acordo com as instruções utilizando os dados já recuperados sem a necessidade de fazer um **SELECT** dentro do outro.

Valeu, Galera! Até a próxima!